# Instagram share opening another app if Instagram is not installed in my device

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, socialshare

I am trying to share Images on Instagram, it's working fine if Instagram is installed on my device, otherwise it will open another app which has the same functionality as Instagram sharing (instead of error throwing).

My Instagram sharing Code is:

```
let instaFilePath = "instagram://library?AssetPath=\(url!.absoluteString)&InstagramCaption=SocialCommerce"
let instaFilePathURL = URL(string: instaFilePath)
let instagramUrl = URL(string: "instagram://app")

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl!) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(instaFilePathURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (completed) in
            print("-----------------------(-)--------------------------\(completed)")
        })
    } else {
        self.showMessage("This feature is not available earlier version then iOS 10.0")
    }
} else {
    self.showMessage("Instagram is not present in your device")
}
```

I have used `CFBundleURLSchemes` and `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` scheme in **Info.plist**

```
 <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
</dict>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? I can't post images to Instagram when Instagram is not installed, I can't even detect if Instagram is installed or not.

Following custom URL Scheme from: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Comment: which app open when instagram is not install?

Comment: The `canOpenURL:` does not check for apps installed, it just tells you if it can open that URL, in Safari or through an app. A valid URL will always return true because the system can actually open it somewhere.

Comment: if any other app implement custom url schema same like instagram then it is possible

Comment: Hi @SPatel, I have recently implemented this in three apps both of these apps open each other  if there is no instagram app installed.

Comment: @ricardopereira, please check here https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Comment: remove `CFBundleURLSchemes` kay and value 

(<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
</dict>)

Comment: why you implement instgram schema in your app

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand **Info.plist**! You are telling to the compiled your app scheme is `instagram`:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

This is why you always get 'true', remove it, then try again with this:

```
if let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL as URL) {
        print("instagram is installed")
    } else {
        print("instagram is not installed")
    }
}else{
    print("failed!")
}
```

[image: ted]

Comment: Hi @Maysam, I have already implemented this code but always return true, even Instagram is not installed.  print("instagram is installed")

Comment: You should not downvote an answer when you have not tried it, it's disrespectful to the community. I removed instagram on my phone and tried the code with the expected result: `instagram is not installed`. I have included a screenshot.